# Prove that all singularity of $\frac{1}{e^z+3z}$ is of order 1

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, singularity

This is a problem from my past QUal: "Prove that all singularity of $$\frac{1}{e^z+3z}$$ is of order 1. You don't need to find the singularities."

Usually this kind of problem is easy to me. My procedure is to find the singularities, and use Taylor series on it. That's why this problem throws me off. I cannot find the poles here: $e^z+3z=0$. And the comment at the end clearly indicates that I took the wrong path. But then how can I prove this?

Comment: Taylor series, perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but where? we can use taylor series at a point. In this case I don't know the points are. And I'm pretty sure they are not nice numbers

Comment: You can reduce the problem to showing that $e^z+3z$ doesn't have any double zeros. Do you see why this reduction is valid? Can you prove the new statement (by, for instance, considering $e^z+3z$ together with its derivative)?

Comment: i just think of the exact same thing. I will write a solution to ask for check

Comment: yes the solution has been provided. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $z=a$ and $1/f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=a$ that is not a pole of order $1$, then both $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a)=0$.  But here $f(a) = e^a +  3a$ and $f'(a) = e^a + 3$, so...